# Android Remote connection with PC

Tags: android

Remote Connection with my computer is not working. Is is not establish connection with pc, it gives me error connection lost.So is there any other way to do this.

Comment: are you sure that it is a programming problem?

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: To do what? post your code